# Update a list with AJAX, but first check if user is already in that list

Tags: php, ajax, list, compare

Hello
I work at a page that initially displays a list with registered users in a contest (an user can be registered multiple times, but every user registered is displayed just once), and this list is updated at a certain time period with AJAX, I would like to display just users that aren't already in that list. Which option would be the best to use for this?

1. Sending the array with the users from the page to the server, and PHP would compare this array with new users and return just users that aren't already in that list (this means that I will send to the server a array with about 10-200 users, at every 30 seconds)
2. Comparing AJAX result with the list of users from the page, and displaying just users that aren't already in the javascript Array (this means that the comparation will be made with javascript)

Comment: I don't understand that part where You want to " display just users that aren't already in that list". Can You explain a bit more?

Comment: where is the problem, in comparing javascript array??

Comment: @experimentX Yes, I'm thinking that comparing a big javascript array can slow down things?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably good to do something like this:

1. **Javascript:** Send time last modified to server - Whenever the last new user was added to the list, not the time of the last request. At first this time will be the current time.
2. **PHP:** Return all users that have entered the contest since this time.
3. **Javascript:** If there are results, detemine which users are unique (however you wish) and add them to the list, updating the time last modified for the next request.

I would think this would be the least amount of data transfer if that is what you are concerned about.

Comment: Yes, I like your idea, but I'm concerned about javascript array. If javascript array has 200 users, isn't to slow this comparation or jQuery.inArray used to check if user is already in this list?!

Comment: I'm not sure - but it seems more efficient to do this than send the whole array of users to the server every 30 seconds. When you get the php response, ONLY return the users who were added (to database) since the last time a user was added (to html list). This assumes you are keeping track of these times in your database or wherever you're keeping the user data.

Comment: but if 2 different users are registered in the same second, but first (X) before ajax request is processed and the second (Y) after the query is executed, then the next request will not return the Y user?!

Comment: That's a good point, but you could just offset the time modified by -1 second. I see no problems doing it that way, if you do I'd like to hear it.